# Unable to change @Html.Partial to <partial> tag in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am new to Razor MVC (making my first real project), and I see from the Microsoft documentation [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that you're not supposed to use `@Html.Partial`, but use either `@await Html.PartialAsync`, or the `<partial>` HTML tag. Unfortunately, neither of those is working for me.

I have the code below in one of my views. The first line in the foreach loop (the `@Html.Partial`) renders the partial view. The next 4 lines each render nothing (I tried each of them individually). It is my understanding based on the documentation that the 2nd line (`<partial name="_InfoCard.cshtml" model="cardModel" />`) is equivalent to the working line.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? Thank you in advance!

Note: I am not sure what the difference is between ASP.NET Core 2.1 and whatever comes with the .NET Framework. When I made this project, I began in Visual Studio Professional 2017, selected `New Project ➔ ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) ➔ MVC`, so I *think* I should have current enough versions of everything for this to work ... I have the following:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc v5.2.4,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Razor v3.2.4,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages v3.2.4

Again, thank you in advance!

```
@using RazerMagazineDashboard.Models
@model RazerMagazineDashboard.Models.SummaryModel
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

@{
    foreach (InfoCardModel cardModel in @Model.CardModels)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_InfoCard.cshtml", cardModel); @* Works well *@

        <partial name="_InfoCard.cshtml" model="cardModel" /> @* Renders nothing *@
        <partial name="_InfoCard.cshtml" model=@cardModel /> @* Renders nothing *@
        <partial name="~/Views/Shared/_InfoCard.cshtml" model="cardModel" /> @* Renders nothing *@
        <partial name="~/Views/Shared/_InfoCard.cshtml" model=@cardModel /> @* Renders nothing *@
    }
}
```

Comment: The docs you are referring to are for asp.net--core-mvc, not mvc-5

Comment: I am having this problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ASP.NET mvc 5 approach

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_InfoCard.cshtml", cardModel); @* Works well *@
```

This is .NET core approach

```
<partial name="_InfoCard.cshtml" model="cardModel" /> @* Renders nothing *@
<partial name="_InfoCard.cshtml" model=@cardModel /> @* Renders nothing *@
<partial name="~/Views/Shared/_InfoCard.cshtml" model="cardModel" /> @* Renders nothing *@
<partial name="~/Views/Shared/_InfoCard.cshtml" model=@cardModel /> @* Renders nothing *@
```

So I think that you project is MVC 5 built using .NET framework, not a .NET core project.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Mine is definitely .Net Core 3.1